# Laravel, how to group a collection by a count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, backend

How can I group a collection using a number. So I made a method that accepts a number then use that number to group the returned collection, so if I pass in a 4 it will group by 4. Below is the original structure of data.

```
{
    'A': [{
        id: 1, 
        id: 2,
        id: 3,
        id: 4,
        id: 5,
        id: 6,
        id: 7
    }],
    'B': [{
        id: 1,
        id: 2,
        id: 3
    }],
    'C': [{
        id: 1,
        id: 2,
        id: 3,
        id: 4
    }]
}
```

Now I want it to format the data this way.

```
{
    'A': [{
        1: [{
            id: 1, 
            id: 2,
            id: 3,
            id: 4
        }],
        2: [{
            id: 5,
            id: 6,
            id: 7
        }]
    }],
    'B': [{
        1: {
            id: 1,
            id: 2,
            id: 3
        }
    }],
    'C': [{
        1: [{
            id: 1,
            id: 2,
            id: 3,
            id: 4
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is my code.

```
public function getAllPlayers( num )
{
    $data = Player::orderBy('familyName', 'asc')
        ->join('teams', 'players.primaryClubId', '=', 'teams.clubId')
        ->select(['players.*', 'teams.teamName', 'teams.teamNickname', 'teams.teamCode'])
        ->get()
        ->unique() //remove duplicates
        ->groupBy(function($item, $key) { //group familyName that starts in same letter
            return substr($item['familyName'], 0, 1);
        });

    return $data;
}
```

I'm really having a hard time solving this in laravel. Btw im using 5.4 version. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The current input, and resultant structure are not clear. First of all, it looks like a JSON structure in the array the value id will be overwritten by the last one. Please provide a better sample with distinct values so that the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `map` functions, like this:

```
$data = Player::orderBy('familyName', 'asc')
    ->join('teams', 'players.primaryClubId', '=', 'teams.clubId')
    ->select(['players.*', 'teams.teamName', 'teams.teamNickname', 'teams.teamCode'])
    ->get()
    ->unique()
    ->groupBy(function($item, $key) {
        return substr($item['familyName'], 0, 1);
    })
    ->map(function ($subCollection) {
        return $subCollection->chunk(4); // put your group size
    });
```